# Proper usage of IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#

I am stuck using generics with IEnumerable

I have a base class of

```
    public class DirectoryObject //Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
    {
        ...
    }
```

where there are two derived classes

```
    public class User : DirectoryObject
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Group : DirectoryObject
    {
        ...
    }
```

I had originally used two separate methods to get the User and Group objects...

```
    public User GetUser(string objectId)
    {
        return _graphConnection.Get<User>(objectId);
    }


    public Group GetGroup(string objectId)
    {
        return _graphConnection.Get<Group>(objectId);
    }
```

---

After writing a lot of repetitive User and Group combinations, I realized that I could just combine it with a generic like so...

```
    public T Get<T>(string objectId) where T : DirectoryObject
    {
        return _graphConnection.Get<T>(objectId);
    }
```

But I am having trouble converting this segment here into a generic IEnumerable...

```
    public IEnumerable<User> ListUser()
    {
        PagedResults pagedResults = _graphConnection.List<User>(null, null);
        return pagedResults.Results.OfType<User>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Group> ListGroup()
    {
        PagedResults pagedResults = _graphConnection.List<Group>(null, null);
        return pagedResults.Results.OfType<Group>();
    }
```

I was thinking along the lines of ...

```
    public IEnumerable<T> List() where T : DirectoryObject
    {
        PagedResults pagedResults = _graphConnection.List<T>(null, null);
        return pagedResults.Results.OfType<T>();
    }
```

But I can't get it to compile, I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I'm drawing blanks at the moment. The error is happening here:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> List() where T : DirectoryObject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify generic type parameter after the method name, that makes this method generic.Or you have to put this method into a generic class where `T` is specified as a generic parameter.Otherwise the compiler has no idea about what the `T` is.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetUsers<T>() where T : DirectoryObject
```

Comment: +1 Well, not "as well", as it's after the method name that it's actually specified. In other places it's just used (at least from the perspective of the method, from the perspective of the return type it's naturally specified in the return type).

Comment: @Guffa - I just noticed what you were saying about the usage of "GetUsers()" as the method name. I was just trying to get the compiler error out of the way first, I didn't even realize the naming was not accurate. Thanks for that too!

Comment: @Svek, you'r welcome.if this answer is solved your problem you should consider accepting it as answer.

Comment: @Selman22 I am still timer locked on it, got about a minute left.

Comment: @Svek: I was actually referring to a wording in the answer, but if that made you think of the naming of the method, fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a "where" constraint on a non-generic method. Even though the return type of `GetUsers()` is generic `IEnumerable<T>`, the method takes no type parameter, so there is no knowledge of what `T` is.

You can create a "pass-through" generic class to alleviate this problem and specify your constraint:

```
public class GenericDirectoryObject<T> : DirectoryObject
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetUsers()
    {
        PagedResults pagedResults = _graphConnection.List<T>(null, null);
        return pagedResults.Results.OfType<T>();
    }
}
```

This class specifies what `T` is on creation, therefore allowing a non-generic function `GetUsers()` to return `IEnumerable<T>`